# How to alter commerce order view access?

Tags: 7, commerce, users

When viewing an order, I want to do checks per order, whether the user may view that order or not.

```
function my_commerce_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['commerce_order']['access callback'] = '_my_commerce_commerce_order_access';
}

function _my_commerce_commerce_order_access($op, $entity = NULL, $account = NULL) {
  return $entity->id == 99; // just for example
}
```

The above did not work.

I didnt find anything like `entity_access_alter` or similar.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`hook_commerce_entity_access_condition_ENTITY_TYPE_alter()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!commerce.api.php/function/hook_commerce_entity_access_condition_ENTITY_TYPE_alter/8) for commerce orders.

You receive the following parameters:

- `$conditions`: The OR conditions group used for the view access query.
- `$context`: An array of contextual information including:

  - `account`: the account whose access to view the entity is being checked
  - `entity_type`: the type of entity in the query
  - `base_table`: the name of the table for the entity type

So it becomes:

```
hook_commerce_entity_access_condition_commerce_order_alter(&$conditions, $context) {
  // If we are not allowed to view the order, leave.
  if (!user_access('some_permission', $context['account'])) {
    return;
  }

  $orders = array(99);

  // add a condition
  $conditions->condition(db_and()
    ->condition($context['base_table'] . '.order_id', $orders, 'IN')
  );
}
```

Comment: the problem is i need to filter on a value that is serialized in the data column

Comment: How bad is it? Should you scan all orders, or only those of a certain user or status or anything else? You could use a secondary query inside this hook to obtain some entities and put their serialized values in the array. But scanning over all orders might take significant time...